# how can Get real-time traffic via laravel-echo-server in public channel without Auth

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, real-time, laravel-echo

I want to get real-time traffic via 
redis, socket.io and laravel-echo-server.
Can I do it?

I want to get a count of current visitors in the site at real-time.
I tried to do it with laravel-echo-server but can't check if a visitor left the site or not found leave with a public channel.
I don't any Auth with visitors

This is the code for users only with automatic laravel-echo- server auth.
I don't need any auth with public or presence channels

```
Echo.channel('get-online')
    .listen('online', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });

      window.Echo.join(`get-online`)
          .here((users) => {
            console.log(users);
          })
          .joining((user) => {
              console.log(user);
          })
          .leaving((user) => {
              console.log(user);
          });
```

Comment: whats the specific question? as long as I understand, yes you can do what you want with that websocket implementation

Comment: can i get count of visitors in public channel without any Auth ?!

Comment: I think there is an API for app and channel statistics. Maybe looking into this helps.

Comment: can i do it with redis, laravel-echo-server and Socket.io ??!